# WPF Can not access DependencyProperty from code

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I'm using WPF 4.5.2, .Net 4.7.2, C# 7

This is the code of my base class fro attached properties

```
   public abstract class BaseAP<Parent, Property> where Parent : BaseAP<Parent , Property>, new()
    {

        #region Public Events


        /// <summary>
        /// Fire when the value changes
        /// </summary>
        public event Action<DependencyObject , DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged = ( sender , e ) => { };


        #endregion


        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// A singleton instance of the parent class
        /// </summary>
        public static Parent Instance { get; private set; } = new Parent();


        #endregion


        #region Attached Properties Definitions

        /// <summary>
        /// The Attached Property for this class
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "Value" , typeof( Property ) , typeof( BaseAP<Parent , Property> ) , new PropertyMetadata( new PropertyChangedCallback( OnValuePropertyChanged ) ) );


        /// <summary>
        /// The callback event when the <see cref="ValueProperty"/> is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The UI-Element that had it's property changed</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for the event</param>
        private static void OnValuePropertyChanged( DependencyObject d , DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            // --- Call the parent function
            Instance.OnValueChanged( d , e );


            // --- Call the event listeners
            Instance.ValueChanged( d , e );            
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the attached property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The element to get the property from</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Property GetValue( DependencyObject d )
        {
            return ( (Property) d.GetValue( ValueProperty ) );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the attached property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The element to set the property to</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set to the element</param>
        public static void SetValue( DependencyObject d , Property value )
        {
            d.SetValue( ValueProperty , value );
        }

        #endregion


        #region Event Methods


        /// <summary>
        /// The method is called when any attached property of this type is changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The ui element that this property was changed for</param>
        /// <param name="e">The arguments for this event</param>
        public virtual void OnValueChanged( DependencyObject d , DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            SetValue( d , (Property) e.NewValue );
        }


        #endregion
    }
```

This code was written originally by Luke Malpass (AngelSix)

My used property looks like this

```
 public class APType : BaseAP<APType , Type> { }
```

In Xaml:

```
<UserControl local:APType.Value={x:Type local:SomeType} />
```

SomeType is a regular class, nothing special

In code behind I'm trying this:

```
Type targetType = GetValue( APType.ValueProperty ) as Type;
```

Unfortunately, *targetType* is always *null*.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in avance

Comment: Where are you calling `GetValue`?

Comment: In the code behind of the UserControl

Comment: The generic parameter *Property* can be set to any type. I'm using it e.g. for boolean, int and even custom classes. In this particular case I'm refering to Type, because I need to access some metadata of local:SomeType

Comment: *When* are you calling it in the code-behind then?

Comment: *local:APType.Value={x:Type local:SomeType}* is set on design time. *Type targetType = GetValue( APType.ValueProperty ) as Type;* is called, when the UserControl is being constructed

Comment: The property cannot be set set before the `UserControl` has been constructed. It works as expected if you call it *after* the property has been as I stated in my answer.

Comment: So move that code to `OnValuePropertyChanged`, or an overridden `OnInitialized` method or a `Loaded` event handler.

Comment: I've found the solution! When I call GetValue in the constructor, the result is always null. When I call GetValue in a method and call the method itself after the UserControl was being constructed, I get the proper result. Thanks a lot to the both of you!

Comment: Ok, I marked the comment which gave me the solution and explained it. Should I delete my question? @Clemens I thought the BaseAP might be interesting, but can delete the original question as well? What do you think, is the best way?

Comment: @GeorgeDuke Whatever you prefer. Note however that this has been asked quite a couple of times. It hasn't got anything to with your generic class. You just can't access property values before they have been set, and that is always after the constructor has finished.

Comment: Do not vandalize this question again.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `GetValue` on the `UserControl` *after* the `Value` attached property has been set:

```
Type type = uc.GetValue(APType.ValueProperty) as Type;
```

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc" local:APType.Value="{x:Type local:SomeType}">
```

The property cannot be set before the `UserControl` has been created.